# Hide JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a drop-down(B) menu that is hidden at first and when a different form(A) is completed, then this drop-down(B) menu is shown. However, when the page loads, the second drop-down(B) menu is not hidden. Code is below and stored in a **php** file

```
<h4>And What Type of Data Are You Focusing On?</h4>
    <select name="library_type" id="library_type">
      <option value="DNA"> DNA </option>
      <option value = "RNA"> RNA </option>
      <option value="WGS"> Whole Genome Sequences</option>
      <option value="WXS">Whole Exome Sequences</option>
      <option value="RNA-Seq">RNA-Seq</option>
      <option value = "miRNA-Seq">miRNA-Seq</option>
      <option value = "VALIDATION">VALIDATION</option>
      <option value = "AMPLICON">AMPLICON</option>
      <option value = "ChIP-Seq">ChIP-Seq</option>
      <option value = "Bisulfite-Seq">Bisulfite-Seq</option>
      <option value = "TARGET_60">TARGET_60</option>
      <option value = "TARGET_50">TARGET_50</option>
      <option value = "TARGET_61">TARGET_61</option>
      <option value = "OTHER">OTHER</option>
    </select>
<h4> What Condition are You Interested in? </h4>
    <select name="tissueState" id="tissueState">
      <option value = "Normal"> Normal </option>
      <option value = "Tumor"> Tumor </option>
      <option value = "Both"> Both </option>
    </select>

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Show me Matches">
</form></center>
```

In a separate file, hideDropDownMenu.js, this is the content of that file.

```
  $("#tissueState").hide();

  $(document).ready(function)(){
    $('#library_type').change(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
    });
  });
```

In the head of the .php file I have this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="hideDropDownMenu.js"></script>
```

Here is how the page looks [image]

Comment: wheres the code for second dropdown ?

Comment: Is there somewhere you can display this issue not working so that we are able see?

Comment: Just a thought... are you sure you are including jQuery?  A screenshot doesn't help us see any errors that maybe getting raised by the browser.

Comment: @xkcd149 I think so, I included     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> in the header file

Comment: @xkcd149 I edited the question describing where I am currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is buggy...

First of all close correctly the document ready and change event.

From this `}` to this `});`
And this `$(document).ready(function)(){` must change in `$(document).ready(function(){`

This is the corrected code:

```
<script>
  $("#tissueState").hide();

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#library_type').change(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/ougvw8kk/

Comment: I see that it works for you but, when I copy that code, it doesn't work for me...

Comment: The reason is because there is JavaScript code and PHP code in the same file... I am trying to move the JavaScript to an external file and call that code.

Comment: If you are putting the script in before the tag in the html it won't work, which is what you are experiencing. Where @Baro's example works, this one does not. https://jsfiddle.net/ougvw8kk/1/

Comment: @xkcd149 In the question I posted, the script is AFTER the tag.

Comment: @Crt Exactly as say xkcd149, if you call "hide" function before the DOM create the span, it won't work, if you want call hide where ever you want, you must wrap in document ready, in this way the hide command wait for DOM ready before call hide.

Comment: @Baro I just said that this script is in a .php file. Don't I need to move the JavaScript code to an external file?

Comment: My last reply is for clarify a concept. Your problem I don't think depend from the included script into the php file, but if this can clear your code, is ever a good thing, for you, and for understand better the code.

Answer (score -1):

In order to hide the dropdown during page load, you need to declare the hide statement inside document ready function.

```
  $(document).ready(function)(){
    $("#tissueState").hide();
    $('#library_type').change(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
    });
  });
```

Comment: If `$("#tissueState").hide();` is executed after the element exists on the page, it's fine and doesn't need to be within a document ready call.

Comment: There's probably a script error in your code. I see in the code you posted you have reference to #library_type but its not declare in the DOM